# How to get nested list items from a JSON Object?

Tags: java

How can I get roles as a list in java here? Following is my JSON Object.

```
{
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "idp-e4f9cb79-0c4f-46a4-8b5f-34dc05e39138",
  "session_state": "9698bd84-6465-4947-98e9-2b477cd119aa",
  "acr": "1",
  "resource_access": {
    "thg-hbgs": {
      "roles": [
        "Admin",
        "Manager",
        "Clerk"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "sid": "9699bd84-6465-4947-98e9-2b477cd119aa",
  "email_verified": true,
  
}
```

Comment: No. I am mapping the scope, sid in an object. But I also need to map the roles which is a list as a property in my object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Jackson* to do it:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(your_json_here);

JsonNode rolesNode = jsonNode.path("resource_access").path("thg-hbgs").path("roles");
if (rolesNode.isArray()) {
    for (JsonNode role : rolesNode) {
        // TODO: handle role
    }
}
```